# Touch offset when using google map in android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing an app using Phonegap for iOS and Android.

The app has a map where the user can see a few markers. I tested the app in iPhone and iPad and the map works great. I tested in a Galaxy Tab and the map has no issues.

But when I tested in a Galaxy 2 I have a problem: the touch is offset. For example in the zoom control if I press Zoom Out (-) the Zoom In (+) is pressed. And if I press outside of the zoom control, the zoom out is pressed.

This is not an issue only of the zoom control, it happens with the markers and info windows as well.
This is how I init the map:

```
  var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions: {
           position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        }
    });
```

The version of android is 2.3.4 and Phonegap v 1.9.0

I attach some screenshots for a better explanation
[image: Here I touched the zoom out button]
[image: Here I touched outside of the zoom control]

Comment: Are you handling touch yourself?  If so, please show the relevant code

Comment: @Simon No I'm not, it's handled by the OS.

Comment: Hi @marcos1490! I know it's an old post, but did you find a solution? I'm working on a Cordova app (not using map) and I have the same bug on Android.

Comment: @kukukk No I didn't, it seems that it was related to the version of Android, but I never found a solution.